# Apache access log not logging content-length for data served via PHP

Tags: php, apache-2.4, log-files

I have a php script that handles files downloads, it sends content-length header properly and the browsers receive it. But in the Apache access log they show up as "-".
In the past this used to work, the bytes showed up on the log, but this is no longer the case.

**PHP Script Requests**
Web Browser -> Nginx -> Apache -> PHP-FPM
https://serverpilot.io/docs/how-serverpilot-configures-your-lamp-stack/

Log entry, where "-" is %b (the file size in bytes)

```
218.200.***.*** - - [29/Dec/2020:00:49:02 +0100] "GET /dll.php?file=File.zip&key=109237902 HTTP/1.0" 200 -
```

Worth noting that if the file is downloaded directly, then the size is logged.

EDIT: Log format:

```
LogFormat "%a %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common
```

Comment: Please show an example log entry demonstrating the problem.

Comment: Added. Thanks for looking into this.

Comment: Well that's interesting. That doesn't look like a normal Apache log entry. Did you define a custom log format? Please show that as well.

Comment: It's what serverpilot uses as logformat added above.

Comment: Added how the server is configured Web Browser -> Nginx -> Apache -> PHP-FPM

Comment: You won't get size in Apache logs since PHP-FPM takes over the request and Apache doesn't download anything in fact. Not sure if changing PHP-FPM from Unix socket to TCP socket or vice versa changes the situation.

Comment: I see. i got some values changing log format from %b to %O http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_logio.html
I don't know how accurate that is.
Do you have a link on how to change socket? I'm very inept when it comes to linux.